# bcm4329 drop unicast packets in android

Tags: android, wifi, adhoc

I use a nexus s with bcm4329 to communicate with a pc in ad hoc mode. bcm4329 sends a arp request to the pc; the pc sends a arp reply back to bcm4329. However, bcm4329 does not deliver the arp reply to upper layer but drops it. Furthermore, bcm4329 also drops unicast udp packets.

Actually, I removed PKT_FILTER_SUPPORT and ARP_OFFLOAD_SUPPORT in bcm4329's makefile and even turned off power management in bcm4329.

Any idea about it? Appreciate it!